flutter local notification onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse not working
I think I have done everything as in the example:
Future<void> _initializeLocalNotifications() async {
    // Android setting
    // androidIcon needs to be a added as a drawable resource to the Android head 
project.
    const androidSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings(_androidIcon);
    // iOS & macOS setting
    const darwinSettings = DarwinInitializationSettings();

    const settings =
        InitializationSettings(android: androidSettings, iOS: darwinSettings);

    await _flutterLocalNotifications.initialize(
      settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (NotificationResponse response) {
        debugPrint(
            "onDidReceiveNotificationResponse received: 
${response.notificationResponseType}");
      },
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
  }

and the callback function outside somewhere:
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
  debugPrint("notificationTapBackground has been called");
}

and an example action:
final _ongoingNotificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
  android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
    ongoingNotificationChannel.id,
    ongoingNotificationChannel.name,
    channelDescription: ongoingNotificationChannel.description,
    importance: ongoingNotificationChannel.importance,
    priority: Priority.low,
    ongoing: true,
    autoCancel: false,
    actions: <AndroidNotificationAction>[
      const AndroidNotificationAction(
        "removeTokenId",
        'Close',
      )
    ],
  ),
....

The method notificationTapBackground is never called. If I put showInterface=true in the action then onDidReceiveNotificationResponse is called. But that is not what I want. I don't want to bring the app into foreground, just execute the code within notificationTapBackground.

The issue is that you have set autoCancel to false and ongoing to true, which means the notification is ongoing and won't be canceled when the user interacts with it.
Please set autoCancel to true. By setting autoCancel to true, the notification will be canceled when the user interacts with it, and the onDidReceiveNotificationResponse callback will be called. You can then handle the notification tap in the callback.

As I mentioned in my question, I want onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse to be called and not onDidReceiveNotificationResponse
